# What is the true behavior of prefetch count in celery?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, prefetch

So this question has been around my mind for a while and it's about the famous `prefetch` in celery.
According to the celery documentation:

> The prefetch limit is a limit for the number of tasks (messages) a worker can reserve for itself.

Since Rabbitmq is used as broker in my case, I also look it up in the rabbitmq documentation and it mentioned:

> This is done by setting a "prefetch count" value using the basic.qos method. The value defines the max number of unacknowledged deliveries that are permitted on a channel.

Based on the documentation, setting prefetch count(or prefetch limit) in celery is just a limit of how many unacknowledged tasks could be there for a consumer.

And my question is why there are so many resources online mentioned that prefetch means a celery worker could **take** numbers of tasks **at one time** in one single network trip communicating with the broker?

In my experience the rabbitmq always send one task at a time to an available consumer.

So when will the scenario of `prefetch tasks in batch at one time` will happen?

My assumption is that maybe it will only happened at the moment when a worker just being started and there are already plenty of tasks inside a queue, so it will fetch multiple tasks up to the prefetch limit at one time?

Please clarify me if I'm wrong.
Thanks for taking your time watching this question!

reference:

1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html
2. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#optimizing-prefetch-limit

I have try to set up a little experiment to test the above situation by using flower to monitor the result.

So basically there's only one publisher and broker without consumer at the beginning.

After I stuffed plenty tasks inside the queue in the broker, the consumer then being started to connects with the broker. (There is only one child process worker of this celery worker with prefetch count set to `6`)

And by what I observed the tasks seems to received by the worker all at very very closed received time but I feel like it still can't be proved that those 6 tasks are received at one single trip from the broker time.

The log from the celery process shows like the snapshot and you could see the time is pretty closed  and some of them are even same.

[image]